# combining iif with mergeMap (rxjs)

Tags: rxjs

`mergeMap` has a handy property: `concurrent: number`, but i need to set it dynamically via one of properties on the stream input.
I wanted to use `iif()`, but i am unable to add `mergeMap` as second or third parameter, like this:

```
iif(
  () => input.concurrentCallsLimit === 1,
  mergeMap(of('foo'), 1),
  mergeMap(of('foo'), 99)
)
```

Can someone please give me example on how to include mergeMap into iif? I keep getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: You provided 'function (source) {
    return source.lift(new MergeMapOperator(project, concurrent));
  }' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable,
```

Answer (score 0):

If you transform `input.concurrentCallsLimit` into an observable (using a Subject for ex), then you could do the following:

```
concurrentCallsLimit$.pipe(
  map(concurrentCallsLimit => (concurrentCallsLimit === 1 ? 1 : 99)),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap(concurrentCallsLimit => mergeMap(of('foo'), concurrentCallsLimit))
);
```

Comment: thanks, i like this hint a lot! But do you think there's a way to have `concurrentCallsLimit` as one of parameters in stream inside `mergeMap`?

What i mean is `of('foo')` should actually be a stream of `({ concurrentCallsLimit, url, params })`. The final stream should work like this:
```
fetchStream.next({ url, params, concurrentCallsLimit })
```